# КатАлог чи каталОг?

Tags: вживання-слів, наголос

На який склад падає наголос? Як буде вірно?

Comment: Наступного разу додайте до запитання Ваші власні спроби знайти відповідь. Також, раджу подивитися [Як мені поставити хороше запитання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Roma Вас заблокувала система за велику кількість питань, які отримали негативну оцінку. Відредагуйте їх за допомогою посилання [edit] щоб вони відповідали вимогам.

Answer (score 1):

З сайту [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/nagolos/nagolos-u-slovi-katalog)
[image]
З СУМ-20

> **[КАТАЛО́Г](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=40909&page=1292)**, у, ч. Список, перелік книжок, рукописів, картин і т. ін., складений у певному порядку, щоб полегшити їх пошук; реєстр (у
>   1 знач.).